# Trying to switch src of <img /> when svg is not supported

Tags: jquery

I am using modernizr to detect when svg is not supported and that is working fine, but for some reason this jQuery is not working.

I am trying to replace the src of a particular  with an id of svg so that its value points to a .png file. This will happen inside the if statement that checks if svg is not supported.

However, the if-statement is working as I put an alert in it and that fired, but this jQuery doesn't seem to be working.

Does anyone know why?

```
$("#svg").attr("src","img/logo.png");
```

I'm using jQuery 1.9.0.

Here is all the JS I have in this site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(!(Modernizr.svg)){
    $("#svg").attr("src","img/logo.png");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `#svg` exists when the condition is checked?

Comment: `$("#svg").attr("src","img/logo.png");` this looks perfectly valid..

Can you show some more code

Comment: @MohammadAdil I edited the question with all the code.

Comment: @ExplosionPills That could be a possibility. I will move the jQuery to the end right before the closing body tag. Isn't that what I should do?

Comment: where is your html source...

Comment: Try replacing `//` with `http://` in the jQuery link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either move your code to before `</body>` or wrap it in `$(function () {})`:

```
$(function () {
    if (!Modernizr.svg) {
        $("#svg").attr('src', 'img/logo.png');
    }
});
```

This will ensure that `#svg` is loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

As Jquery is not working for you this could be the problem

Include jquery properly like this (missing `http:`)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And as Expolosion Pills said

wrap it in `$(function () {}):`